# How to access method mysql_fetch_array of database class in other php file?

Tags: php

Below is code of database.php file.

```
     <?php

    class Database
{
var $con;
var $db;
var $result;
var $data;


public function connect($server="localhost",$uname="cccsql",$pword="ccc123",$db="trainees_jinal")
{
    try
    {
        $con=mysql_connect($server,$uname,$pword);
        if(!$con)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: Cannot connect to the server");
            return;
        }

        $db=mysql_select_db($db,$con);
        if(!$db)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: Cannot connect to the database");
            return;
        }
        return $this;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function insert($sql)
{
    try
    {
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$res)
            throw new Exception("record insertion failed...");

        if($res)
        {
            return mysql_insert_id();    
        }

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function update($sql)
{
    try
    {
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$res)
            throw new Exception("record updation failed...");
        return $res;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
public function delete($sql)
{
    try
    {
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$res)
            throw new Exception("record deletion failed...");
        return $res;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function fetchAll($sql)
{
    try
    {
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$res)
            throw new Exception("error on query execution record...");

        $arr=array();


        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            array_push($arr,$row);

        }
        return $arr;

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
public function fetchRow($sql)
{
    try
    {
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$res)
            throw new Exception("error on query execution record...");

        if($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            return $row;
        }
        return NULL;            
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
public function num_fields($result)
{
    return mysql_num_fields($result);
}
public function field_name($result,$i)
{
    return mysql_field_name($result,$i);
}


private function wrap_with_quotes($data)  
{  
    return sprintf('"%s"', $data);  
}  
 ?>
```

And now below is my code for display.php file.

```
   <br/>
   <a href="index.php"><button>New Registration</button></a>

       <br><br><br/>
    <form method="post">
     <table width="" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="" align="center" >
            <tr>
             <th>Check</th>
             <th> ID</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Age</th>
             <th>Gender</th>
             <th>Contact</th>
             <th>Email</th>
             <th>UserName</th>
             <th>Password</th>
             <th>Billing Address </th>
             <th>Shipping Address </th>
             <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php

         require_once 'database.php';
          $database = new Database;
        $q="SELECT * FROM personalinfo INNER JOIN addrsinfo ON personalinfo.id=addrsinfo.id";


while($rows=$database->fetchRow($q))
{
?>
 <tr>
        <td align="center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
        <td ><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
        <td width="40%" nowrap="2"><? echo $rows['name'];?> </td>
       <td width="10%"><? echo $rows['age']; ?></td>
       <td width="20%"><? echo $rows['gender']; ?></td>
        <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['contact']; ?></td>
        <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
        <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['uname']; ?></td>
        <td width="20%"><? echo $rows['paswrd']; ?></td>
        <td width="50%"><? echo $rows['billaddr']; ?></td>

         <td width="50%"><? echo $rows['shipaddr']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?=$rows['id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
   </tr>


   <?php  }?>
   </table>  


        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Multi Delete"> 
            </td>
        </tr>





      <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$checkbox[] = $_POST['checkbox'];

if(sizeof($checkbox[0])>1)
{
    $id=implode(",",$checkbox[0]);

    $query = "DELETE FROM personalinfo WHERE id IN($id)";
    $database->delete($query);
}
else
{

   $id=$checkbox[0][0];
   $query = "DELETE FROM personalinfo WHERE id='$id'";
   $database->delete($query);

}
echo"<script>window.location='display.php';</script>";
 }




if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$checkbox[] = $_POST['checkbox'];

if(sizeof($checkbox[0])>1)
{
    $id=implode(",",$checkbox[0]);

    $query = "DELETE FROM addrsinfo WHERE id IN($id)";
     $database->delete($query); 
}
else
{

   $id=$checkbox[0][0];
   $query = "DELETE FROM addrsinfo WHERE id='$id'";
    $database->delete($query); 

}
echo"<script>window.location='display.php';</script>";
}

 ?>


</form>      

      </table>
```

So my question is how can i use FetchRow and FetchAll method in my display.php file.I am a beginner and trying to learn OOP with PHP.Help me as soon as possible.

Please check the below code and help me as my loop goes in infinite mode.

```
     <?php
     require_once 'database.php';
     $database = new Database;
     $database->connect();
     $q="SELECT * FROM personalinfo INNER JOIN addrsinfo ON  personalinfo.id=addrsinfo.id";
      ?>
      <?php
while($rows=$database->fetchRow($q))
{
?>
<tr>
        <td align="center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
        <td ><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
        <td width="40%" nowrap="2"><? echo $rows['name'];?> </td>
       <td width="10%"><? echo $rows['age']; ?></td>
       <td width="20%"><? echo $rows['gender']; ?></td>
        <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['contact']; ?></td>
        <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
        <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['uname']; ?></td>
        <td width="20%"><? echo $rows['paswrd']; ?></td>
        <td width="50%"><? echo $rows['billaddr']; ?></td>

         <td width="50%"><? echo $rows['shipaddr']; ?></td>

   </tr>


   <?php  }?>
```

Comment: you need to first change $database = new Database; to $database = new Database();

Then let me know what error you are getting

Comment: @RajivRisi She already included the file

Comment: I have used require_once in form tag.But my question is the row is not being displayed on the form but it entry of new row is done in database.Also in output form i get label bur error comes along with like this :-"error on query execution record...".So wats the mistake?Am i Writing wrongly in display.php file's while loop for accessing FetchRow method of database.php?

Comment: Call the function connect before proceed any mysql things. Not yet you connected the mysql.

Comment: You might want to check documentation first. There are a lot of good examples on www.php.net, especially in comments section. Your question is the basic usage of mysql connection in PHP. You also might consider using PDO instead of your own class. It does what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of it and use it, for example:

```
include "database.php";
$database = new Database();
```

Now you can use it the way you tried already:

`$database->fetchRow();`

Another method would be, to make your class `static` so you can call it everywhere **without** having to instanciate it over and over again. This is very useful for database classes because you normally need them in your whole project. So you have to turn all your functions and attributes in your class static. Afterwards you can call your database class like this:

```
include "database.php";
Database::fetchRow();
```

More informations here

http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.php

Comment: I will prefer 1st method for creating the instance.But still i am not getting you.Can you see my database.php and display .php file and suggest me what shall i write?

Comment: @Muskaan actually you have to use the connect statement, before you can fetch something from the database.

Comment: @Muskaan aswell your missing the `(` and `)` after your new Database

Answer (score 0):

Connect your database first before using mysql fetch queries. Add the line below to `$database = new Database;`

```
$database->connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use while on that code.. because fetchall function will return an array variable.. you have to use "for" looping instead of while..
create function to count row number of the reccord..
and then loop for each array